# Polymer Cli Vs PWA starter Kit

Tags: polymer, pwa-starter-kit

What is the difference between Polymer Cli and PWA starter Kit? I am eager to build PWA with web components using Polymer but I am confused about these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PWA Starter Kit is a set of sample apps](https://polymer.github.io/pwa-starter-kit/sample-apps/) based on lit-element, the latest Web Components library made by the Polymer team. You could use one of the sample apps in the PWA starter kit as a template for your own app, and/or to look at the code and become familiar with lit-element.

[Polymer CLI is a set of command line tools](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) for working with the stuff made by the Polymer team. You would use Polymer CLI commands like `polymer serve` to run your PWA starter kit app in a local development server, or `polymer build` to package it for deployment to a web server.

Answer (score 1):

Pwa starter Kit project is no longer maintained

source: https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/issues/373

use open-wc instead